# Am I doing anything wrong? Find whether the following are group actions

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb Z$ be a group and the set is $X=\mathbb Q$. Check whether the following are group actions:

1. $p(z,x)=2^zx$
2. $p(z,x)=(z+1)x$
3. $p(z,x)=x^{z+1}$

But it seems like all three don't have the criteria that $p(zq,x)=p(z,qx)$. Am I getting it wrong? Or is the criteria actually $p(zq,x)=p(z,p(q,x))$?

Thanks!

Comment: The latter. Changing notation a bit, a group action of $G$ on a set $X$ is a function $f: G \to \text{Map}(X, X)$ such that $f(gh) = f(g) f(h)$. It's often written $g.x = f(g)(x)$, so that the latter condition then becomes $(gh).x = g.(h.x)$. The group multiplication defines the product in the first argument of $p(zq, x)$, but you already need to have some sort of group action to define the $qx$ in $p(z, qx)$; here $X$ is just a set, and there isn't an automatic definition of what it means to apply any element $q\in G$ to $x\in X$.

Comment: Then none of the above is a group action? Or maybe i'm still missing something

Comment: The first one is, for example: If we set $z.x = 2^z x$, then $z.(z'.x) = z.(2^{z'} x) = 2^{z + z'}x = (z + z').x$. Note that $G = \mathbb{Z}$ is a group under addition, so that $p(zq, x)$ is actually $p(z + q, x)$.

Comment: Ah, that's my mistake. Thank you very much!